# Collaborative website of Field Recording

Tags: field, recording, websites

Hello,

Do you know a great collaborative field recording's website where you can post, share and download field recording's sound for free ?

Thanks for your anwsers

Answer (score 3):

closest answer is the [sound collector's club.](http://thesoundcollectorsclub.com/)  Its not free, but its very cheap - and its super high quality, so well worth the price of admission.

Comment: Yea Rene, i checked that out after the TB episode on it, I'm almost certain i'm going to join pretty soon.

Answer (score 2):

The Freesound Project
http://www.freesound.org/

Comment: Definitely bump for Freesound, just be prepared to root through a lot of crud to find some gold.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how good your dutch is  (or your skills at translate.google.com) check out [this](http://www.geluidvannederland.nl/about).

Disclaimer: I conceptualized and set this site up in collaboration with [the Dutch Instute of Sound and Vision](http://www.beeldengeluid.nl/en). It's got over 2300 professionally recorded sounds from archives and users. You can contribute also, but it's intended as a Dutch sound archive.
So it may not be very meaningful to contribute sounds from your country. But invite you to have a look at it. We use soundcloud by the way.

Arnoud